# How to combine two separate arrays to single array of dictionaries?

Tags: arrays, dictionary, swift2

Given two separate arrays, I would like to combine those into a single array of dictionaries.

For example, given:

```
var array = ["myDataOne", "myDataTwo", "myDataThree", "myDataFour"]

var array_second = ["apple", "banana", "orange", "kiwi"]
```

And I would like that my array to look like:

```
dictionnary[0] -> dataOne: "myDataOne", dataSecond: "apple"
dictionnary[1] -> dataOne: "myDataTwo", dataSecond: "banana"
dictionnary[2] -> dataOne: "myDataThree", dataSecond: "orange"
dictionnary[3] -> dataOne: "myDataFour", dataSecond: "kiwi"
```

I'm coding in Swift 2 using Xcode 7 B5.

**EDIT** : Just to clarify, in fact the final array should look like this:

```
[[dataOne: "myDataOne", dataSecond: "apple"],[dataOne: "myDataTwo", dataSecond: "banana"],[dataOne: "myDataThree", dataSecond: "orange"],[dataOne: "myDataFour", dataSecond: "kiwi"]]
```

So `array[0]` must return something like `[dataOne: "myDataOne", dataSecond: "apple"]` and if i do `array[0].dataOne` it must return "myDataOne".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The typical procedural approach would be:

```
var result = [[String: String]]()
for var i = 0; i < array.count; i++ {
    result.append(["dataOne": array[i], "dataSecond" : array_second[i]])
}
```

--

You can also do this functionally:

```
let result = zip(array, array_second).map { ["dataOne" : $0.0, "dataSecond" : $0.1] }
```

Comment: As simple as that.
Thank you very much Rob.